# How to replace specific values in a database column for SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, substring

I am new and a beginner to SQL Query and have faced problems, thus I hope I can seek some help. I have tried searching online but to no avail.

I am targeting to replace certain values in a column.
For example

### Staff_ID

1234962D
4321739P

Is it possible to replace the first four digits with asterisk (*).
Something like this :

### Staff_ID

****962D
****739P

I have tried using replace, left and substring, but I have faced problems, like the system picking and showing the first 4 digits only.

Do appreciate any help!

Comment: What have you tried with substring exactly?  You should be able to use a combination of substring and length.   Also, is "1234962D 4321739P" an example of two different staff id's or just one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT '****' + SUBSTRING(Staff_ID, 5, LEN(Staff_ID) - 4)
```

will give you `****962D` if the input value is `1234962D`.  As FuzzyTree says, you can use CONCAT, but only if you're using SQL Server 2012 or later.  It's useful in that it implicitly converts null values to an empty string.  It's less useful if you are concerned about backward compatibility issues or porting code to other flavors of SQL.

Comment: I tried what you have stated, however I received an error message 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1234693D' to data type int.'

Comment: Sorry about that.  It's a typo; I've put a paren in the wrong place.  I've corrected (and tested) it.  It should be the (length of the staff id) - 4, not the length of (the staff id - 4).  Obviously you can't subtract 4 from the staff id, since it's not a number.

Comment: p. s. If the length of your field will never vary, you can get rid of the LEN expression altogether.  For example, if the length is always 8, you can just put 4 instead of LEN(Staff_ID) - 4.

Comment: You're welcome.  cjay's STUFF function is worth looking into as well, if you aren't going to be using MySQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try STUFF function?

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/stuff.php

from the site:

```
STUFF( source_string, start, length, add_string )
```

So you can use it like this

```
STUFF(column, 1, 4, '****')
```

Comment: I've never used that. Looks like a simpler solution than mine.  However, it's only available in SQL Server, not MySQL or Oracle, and the OP hasn't specified which flavor of SQL he's using.

Comment: There is "sql-server" tag

Comment: Got a point there cjay.  :)  Looks like I need to get in the habit of checking tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `concat` and `substring`

```
select concat('****',substring('1234962D4321739P', 5, 4)
    ,'****',substring('1234962D4321739P', 13, 4));
```